# get an existing Amplify app with AWS CDK Amplify lib

Tags: typescript, aws-amplify, aws-cdk

I would like to get hold of an existing Amplify app using the AWS CDK so I can add custom domains to it.
I see in the docs that it is possible to create a whole Amplify app and deploy it, but not **getting an existing one** that is already deployed.
I was hoping the lib to have a function like "getAppByName" or something.
Is there a way to achieve that, preferably using CDK v2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [@aws-cdk/aws-amplify-alpha](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-amplify-alpha-readme.html) module's App construct has a [fromAppId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-amplify-alpha.App.html#static-fromwbrappwbridscope-id-appidspan-classapi-icon-api-icon-experimental-titlethis-api-element-is-experimental-it-may-change-without-noticespan) static method. It returns a read-only [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html#resources_external) to an existing (external) Amplify App.  The return type is `IApp`, which you can use in other constructs, but not use to modify your existing App.

N.B. This read-only pattern applies to all CDK `fromSomethingId` type methods that return an `ISomething` construct.

Comment: thank you. I guess Ill have to get Amplify deployed via cdk as well